# Save model with OneToOne field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I have created a profile-model to extend the default django user (using django 1.6)
But I can't save the profile-model correctly.

Here is my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    mobilephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

Here is my celery-task which updates personrecords from a wdsl file:

```
@task()
def update_local(user_id):

    url = 'http://webservice.domain.com/webservice/Person.cfc?wsdl'

    try:
        #Make SUDS.Client from WSDL url
        client = Client(url)
    except socket.error, exc: 
        raise update_local.retry(exc=exc)
    except BadStatusLine, exc:
        raise update_local.retry(exc=exc)


    #Make dict with parameters for WSDL query
    d = dict(CustomerId='xxx', Password='xxx', PersonId=user_id)

    try:
        #Get result from WSDL query
        result = client.service.GetPerson(**d)
    except (socket.error, WebFault), exc:
        raise update_local.retry(exc=exc)
    except BadStatusLine, exc:
        raise update_local.retry(exc=exc)



    #Soup the result
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result)


    #Firstname
    first_name = soup.personrecord.firstname.string

    #Lastname
    last_name = soup.personrecord.lastname.string

    #Email
    email = soup.personrecord.email.string

    #Mobilephone
    mobilephone = soup.personrecord.mobilephone.string



    #Get the user    
    django_user = User.objects.get(username__exact=user_id)

    #Update info to fields
    if first_name:
        django_user.first_name = first_name.encode("UTF-8")

    if last_name:    
        django_user.last_name = last_name.encode("UTF-8")

    if email:
        django_user.email = email


    django_user.save() 



    #Get the profile    
    profile_user = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=django_user)

    if mobilephone:
        profile_user.mobilephone = mobilephone

    profile_user.save()
```

The `django_user.save()` is working fine, but the `profile_user.save()` is not working. Im getting this error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'mobilephone'`

Anyone see what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found 2 bugs in your code:

- `get_or_create` method returns tuple (objects, created), so you have to change your code to:

  `profile_user = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=django_user)[0]`

  or, if you need information about state of returned object (just created or not) you should use

  `profile_user, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=django_user)`

  and then rest of code will work correctly.
- In your profile model the field `models.CharField` must have `max_length` argument declared.
- You don't need to use `()` in `@task` decorator. You only have to do this if you pass arguments to the decorator.
- Also you can avoid build user profile with one to one database connection using [django custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! I forgot the max_length in my question, but not in my code.

Comment: I didn't know that, but it looks strange because without this parameter you can't run django server ( model validation will fail )